# CakePHP not working as expectetd on apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

(*note the "edit")

I'm following the tutorial (bookmarker) and after datasource config, i get the default page

so far so good. Now i've followed the baking procedure and it was successful. however.. the default page stays!
I'm not routed to the app..

Strangely, using the builtin server (`bin\cake server`) shows the expected result (accessing `localhost:8765/bookmarks`).

It seems like an apache issue - but i can't figure it out.

1. I've verified that i have both .htaccess files in the app (`/.htaccess` and `webroot/.htaccess`)
2. I've verified that the httpd.conf is set to `Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All`
3. The server was restarted.

I'm using win7 pro & wamp (bitnami's dist)

[image]

---

### edit

I've also tried VirtualHost. added to `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bookmarker
  DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\bookmarker"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

changed the `hosts` file (`127.0.0.1    bookmarker`)

Go the same results.

Comment: Do you mean empty `.htaccess` files?

Comment: No - they are  not empty, both were copied by the composer and seems intact (as shown in the tutorial)

Comment: Have you created an Apache host with `DocumentRoot` pointing to full `webroot` path on disk?

Comment: No. i've followed the tutorial*. and i access the project by using `http://localhost/bookmarker`. it shows the project as shown in the picture..

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting

Comment: I understand you haven't shared much code or settings because you've followed the tutorial steps verbatim (though some of the instructions are only textual descriptions) but you've just shown a virtual host that doesn't point to `webroot`. I'm afraid that details actually matter because computers follow orders literally. Are you trying to run the CakePHP app as subdirectory in a larger site?

Comment: (note the edit, i tried v-hosting now as well, with the same results)
I use wamp, and it works. i have other applications there that uses native php or cake 1.3, both works fine (with routing).

Comment: Sorry if I've failed to note something in your edit. I really cannot see that it includes the word "webroot". Let's wait and see if some other Stack Overflow user can be of more help.

Comment: Have you checked the Routes file to see where is "/" going to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your URL rewriting configurations. In your Apache Configuration file (httpd.conf)

use

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Also make sure that rewrite_module is not commented (remove # from beginning).

Answer (score 1):

Comment these two lines in routes.php file:

`$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);`

`$routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);`

And add these lines in routes.php file:

`$routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*');`

`$routes->connect('/:controller/*', ['action' => 'index']);`

routes.php file is responsible for your application's routes and redirections.